# Xpath for Decendent Child

Tags: c#, xml

I have a response XML in which I am trying to find the id of Entry tag, but any combination is yielding null always.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<status feed="http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int" xmlns="http://superfeedr.com/xmpp-pubsub-ext">
<http code="200">Fetched (ring) 200 242 and parsed 2/42 entries</http>
<next_fetch>1970-01-18T20:24:54.289Z</next_fetch>
<entries_count_since_last_maintenance>35</entries_count_since_last_maintenance>
<velocity>65.3</velocity>
<popularity>3.713318235496007</popularity>
<generated_ids>true</generated_ids>
<title>BBC News - Home</title>
<period>242</period>
<last_fetch>1970-01-18T20:24:54.045Z</last_fetch>
<last_parse>1970-01-18T20:24:54.045Z</last_parse>
<last_maintenance_at>1970-01-18T20:24:07.350Z</last_maintenance_at>
</status>
<link title="BBC News - Home" rel="alternate" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/" type="text/html"/>
<link title="BBC News - Home" rel="image" href="https://news.bbcimg.co.uk/nol/shared/img/bbc_news_120x60.gif" type="image/gif"/>
<title>BBC News - Home</title>
<updated>2018-11-15T14:59:15.000Z</updated>
<id>bbc-news-home-2018-11-15-14</id>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:as="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/" xmlns:sf="http://superfeedr.com/xmpp-pubsub-ext" xml:lang="en">
<id>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-46225486</id>
<published>2018-11-15T14:44:37.000Z</published>
<updated>2018-11-15T14:44:37.000Z</updated>
<title>Trump attacks Mueller's Russia inquiry as 'absolutely nuts'</title>
<summary type="text">The US president says the Russia inquiry is a "total mess" and calls investigators "a disgrace".</summary>
<link title="Trump attacks Mueller's Russia inquiry as 'absolutely nuts'" rel="alternate" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-46225486" type="text/html" xml:lang="en"/>
<link title="Trump attacks Mueller's Russia inquiry as 'absolutely nuts'" rel="thumbnail" href="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/E64B/production/_104355985_gettyimages-1060191940.jpg" type="image/jpeg" xml:lang="en"/>
</entry>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:as="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/" xmlns:sf="http://superfeedr.com/xmpp-pubsub-ext" xml:lang="en">
<id>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-46221238</id>
<published>2018-11-15T14:35:47.000Z</published>
<updated>2018-11-15T14:35:47.000Z</updated>
<title>Ethiopia arrests former deputy spy chief Yared Zerihun</title>
<summary type="text">Prime Minister Abiy Ahmed promised to combat corruption and rights abuses when he took office.</summary>
<link title="Ethiopia arrests former deputy spy chief Yared Zerihun" rel="alternate" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-46221238" type="text/html" xml:lang="en"/>
<link title="Ethiopia arrests former deputy spy chief Yared Zerihun" rel="thumbnail" href="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/52E9/production/_104352212_872d41ed-8ac9-4b7b-abfc-b4d898a71670.jpg" type="image/jpeg" xml:lang="en"/>
</entry>
</feed>
```

to fetch the id  these are the combination I tried

1. `"/feed/entry/id/text()"`
2. `"entry/id/text()"`
3. `doc.GetElementsByTagName("entry").SelectNodes("id/text()")I

i can go to id by iteration with childNodes but what will be XPath for that.

but if I try "/*" on the whole document it gives me one node count. why ?

Comment: you need to fetch ids of all `entry` node?

Comment: @er-shoaib yes,

Comment: i added answer to get all ids text directly with only single XPath expression. view it might be it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You xml contains namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` at root level node `<feed>`

And you are using `/feed/entry/id/text()` these kind of XPath but these path are not suitable for this xml and that's why you can't get any desired value.

You need to use below XPath to get id's of all `<entry>` node.

```
var ids = doc.SelectNodes("//*[name()='feed']/*[name()='entry']/*[name()='id']/text()");
```

Here i created a sample console app for demonstration purpose.

```
class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

        var ids = doc.SelectNodes("//*[name()='feed']/*[name()='entry']/*[name()='id']/text()");

        foreach (XmlNode id in ids)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The xml elements in the xml are declared within the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` xml namespace.
This namespace has to be considered in the `XPATH`statement.

You have to register this namespace with an `XmlNamespaceManager` and apply the chosen prefix (here:`x`) in the `XPATH`statement as: `//x:feed/x:entry/x:id`.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
String pathToYourXmlFile = @"c:\folder\file.xml";
doc.Load(pathToYourXmlFile);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
XmlNodeList ids = doc.SelectNodes("//x:feed/x:entry/x:id", nsmgr);
foreach (XmlNode id in ids)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification , let me work with your changes